# Can I change the anti-aliasing method of a lot of layers at once?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a lot of text layers (I'm rendering up a keyboard). Is there any way to change the anti-aliasing setting on all of the layers at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your type-tool active, go to your Layers window and select all the text layers you want to update.  Change the type-tool anti-alias setting and it will update all the selected text layers.  This works since at least CS3.